# Oculus Rift in Linux

Tags: linux, debian, gaming

Sorry if this isn't the right place for this question. I do realize this is a somewhat experimental piece of hardware. Still, it would be nice to see how much progress can be made here.

I'm running Debian Jessie. I have a Oculus Rift Dev Kit v1. lsusb does not show an ID string:

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2833:0001
```

When I try to play HL2 with it, the option to enable VR is grayed out. Launching with -vr option of course.

This Oculus Rift is confirmed working in Windows 7.

Is there any sort of Oculus Rift tuning utility for Linux? Anything I need to do to get this working? Any sort of driver installation? From googling, it's supposed to be completely "plug and play" but that unfortunately doesn't seem to be the case here.

Thanks!!

Comment: doesn't seem to be supported as of yet... https://developer.oculusvr.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=2678

Comment: HL2 aside, is there a Linux util for the OR? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oculus Rift should show up in linux as an external monitor. Depending on your graphics card, This can be set up as simply an an external display. I would suggest NVidia XServer settings (if using NVidia).

No Utils or GUI form of a toolbox seem to exist.

Comment: No problem, glad to help another linux user ;)